# NoClassDef after after Adding multiDexEnabled

Tags: android, android-multidex

Hey I have a large android project after adding large number of files I started getting

```
 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
```

so I searched for my problem and I found a solution is by adding this property to the Gradle file but after I added the project build successfully

but when I run the project I'm getting NoClassDef error on some of my fragment and activity

this is my gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cloudappers.com.rta_ca"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':bounceScroller')
    compile project(':SwipeMenu')
    compile project(':indicator')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http.jar')
    compile('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.leocardz:aelv:1.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


}
```

it's working on android 5 but not on 4.4 and prior

Any help?

Comment: @AndiGeeky thanks i have posted my gradle

Comment: If you are using 'compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])' then no need to use : compile files('libs/android-async-http.jar')   
compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar') ..So please remove it..!!

Comment: do i need to change any thing in my manifest if i want to add multidex enabled?

Comment: Thanks man it worked

Comment: why u dont provide it as an answer for future help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your gradle Here :

```
1. compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
2. compile files('libs/android-async-http.jar')   
3. compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
```

Now if you used line 1 then no need to add line 2 & 3.

Reason is that `'compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])'` includes all jar file to gradle that is in libs folder..

So remove line 2 & 3.

Thanks.!!